# How to use the application server libraries in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

i just started working with Intellij, and it have some things i don't clearly understand.
One of these things is that i don't know how to tell the IDE to use the application server libraries, e.g the persistence api or the CDI api, both bundled with glassfish server. So even if my project is configured with glassfish server, if i type "@Named" in one of my classes, the IDE shows an error saying it could not recognize the @Named annotation.
And i dont think i should add the cdi libs in the project, there must be an way to make the IDE recognize the libraries from the server.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea can automatically download the Java EE jars for you and configure them. You must start with intent:

[image]

Once IDEA fetches the jars, you will find in your project configuration:

[image]

and new library

[image]